# slideToggle на чистом js или как не ждать полной загрузки страницы, чтобы узнать высоту элемента

Tags: javascript, jquery, алгоритм, функции

Я хочу написать аналог `slideToggle` из jQuery на чистом JavaScript, но не понимаю как он работает.
Что я обычно делаю, чтобы добиться поведения `slideToggle` в JS:

Я выбираю нужный мне элемент, потом мне надо дождаться загрузки страницы, чтобы посчитать высоту элемента(вместе текстом), если не ждать загрузки, то посчитается неполная высота.
При клике я просто меняю класс `active`, если хочу задать блоку какие-то стили при `active`, но проблема в том, что мне нужно ждать полной загрузки страницы, чтобы посчитать высоту элемента вместе со всем контентом внутри него.
В данном примере я сделал анимацию с помощью transition

```js
let elem = document.querySelector('.elem');

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
 let heightElem = elem.offsetHeight;
 elem.style.height = '0px';
 btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  btn.classList.toggle('active');
  elem.classList.toggle('active');
  if (btn.classList.contains('active')) {
   elem.style.height = heightElem + 'px';
  } else {
   elem.style.height = '0px';
  }
 });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700|Open+Sans:400,600,700|Raleway:400,900&display=swap');

*, *:before, *:after {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.elem {
 width: 300px;
 padding: 0 10px;
 background-color: #f4f7ca;
 transition: height .5s linear;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#btn {
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 15px;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-weight: bold;
 transition: background-color .2s linear,
    border-color .2s linear,
    color .2s linear;
 border: 2px solid transparent;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
       -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
}

#btn.active {
 background-color: white;
 border-color: black;
 color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="elem">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>

<div id="btn">Раскрыть/открыть</div>
```

Но можно не зависисеть от стиля `transition` и сделать на js анимацию:

```js
let elem = document.querySelector('.elem');

let reqAnimFrame = (function() {
    return requestAnimationFrame       ||
           mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
           webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
           oRequestAnimationFrame      ||
           msRequestAnimationFrame     ||
    function(callback) {
        setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    }
})();

function animate({timing, draw, duration}) {

  let start = performance.now();

  reqAnimFrame(function animate(time) {
    // timeFraction изменяется от 0 до 1
    let timeFraction = (time - start) / duration;
    if (timeFraction > 1) timeFraction = 1;

    // вычисление текущего состояния анимации
    let progress = timing(timeFraction);

    draw(progress); // отрисовать её

    if (timeFraction < 1) {
      reqAnimFrame(animate);
    }

  });
}

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
 let heightElem = elem.offsetHeight;
 elem.style.height = '0px';
 btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  btn.classList.toggle('active');
  elem.classList.toggle('active');
  if (btn.classList.contains('active')) {
   animate({
    duration: 500,
    timing(timeFraction) {
     return timeFraction;
    },
    draw(progress) {
     elem.style.height = progress * heightElem + 'px';
    }
   });
  } else {
   animate({
    duration: 500,
    timing(timeFraction) {
     return timeFraction;
    },
    draw(progress) {
     let antiProgress = 1 - progress;
     elem.style.height = antiProgress * heightElem + 'px';
    }
   })
  }
 });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700|Open+Sans:400,600,700|Raleway:400,900&display=swap');

*, *:before, *:after {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.elem {
 width: 300px;
 padding: 0 10px;
 background-color: #f4f7ca;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#btn {
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 15px;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-weight: bold;
 transition: background-color .2s linear,
    border-color .2s linear,
    color .2s linear;
 border: 2px solid transparent;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
       -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
}

#btn.active {
 background-color: white;
 border-color: black;
 color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="elem">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>

<div id="btn">Раскрыть/открыть</div>
```

Но всё равно я упираюсь в то, что если, я хочу, чтобы элемент был скрыт по умолчанию, мне нужно дождаться загрузки контента, посчитать высоту и только после этого скрыть элемент. Чтобы узнавать высоту элемента, мне нужно асинхронно запускать функцию, чтобы узнавать его высоту? Как это сделать, если это так, а если нет, то что делать, чтобы сделать подобную функцию slideToggle?

Comment: Вы можете не зависеть от transition, но вам всё равно придётся зависеть от opacity.

Comment: @Kirill а зачем `opacity`? slideToggle в jquery при конце анимации использует просто `display: none`, чтобы убрать элемент из основного потока документа. А `opacity` просто сделает элемент прозрачным

Comment: Opacity не единственный пример. Я лишь хотел сказать, что на 100% чистом js не выйдет. Всегда будет зависимость от стиля, будь то opacity height или что-то ещё. Но в любом случае сначала будет идти стиль, изменяющий отображение элемента, а потом js. Иначе "скачков" не избежать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const container = document.querySelector('.container');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (container.classList.contains('container--active')) {
    container.classList.remove('container--active');
    container.style.maxHeight = 0;
  } else {
    container.classList.add('container--active');
    container.style.maxHeight = container.scrollHeight + 'px';
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height .3s ease;
}

button {
  position: fixed;
  top: 8px;
  right: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem impedit temporibus ipsum quidem accusantium eveniet rerum saepe dolorem soluta necessitatibus. Unde omnis alias quam doloribus debitis eveniet, sunt cumque quia laborum tempore dolore
  tempora? Nihil itaque sint quis impedit enim delectus laudantium odit. Et assumenda ad nostrum, nisi maiores quo!</div>

<button>Show/Hide</button>
```

Comment: Хм, вы предлагаете, что можно просто при клике каждый раз просто считать высоту? Не подумал об этом

Comment: @meine Круто. Просто и лаконично.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let elem = document.querySelector('.elem');

let reqAnimFrame = (function() {
    return requestAnimationFrame       ||
           mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
           webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
           oRequestAnimationFrame      ||
           msRequestAnimationFrame     ||
    function(callback) {
        setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    }
})();

function animate({timing, draw, duration}) {

  let start = performance.now();

  reqAnimFrame(function animate(time) {
    // timeFraction изменяется от 0 до 1
    let timeFraction = (time - start) / duration;
    if (timeFraction > 1) timeFraction = 1;

    // вычисление текущего состояния анимации
    let progress = timing(timeFraction);

    draw(progress); // отрисовать её

    if (timeFraction < 1) {
      reqAnimFrame(animate);
    }

  });
}

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
 let heightElem = elem.offsetHeight;
  elem.classList.toggle('hide');
 elem.style.height = '0px';
 btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  btn.classList.toggle('active');
  elem.classList.toggle('active');
  if (btn.classList.contains('active')) {
   animate({
    duration: 500,
    timing(timeFraction) {
     return timeFraction;
    },
    draw(progress) {
     elem.style.height = progress * heightElem + 'px';
    }
   });
  } else {
   animate({
    duration: 500,
    timing(timeFraction) {
     return timeFraction;
    },
    draw(progress) {
     let antiProgress = 1 - progress;
     elem.style.height = antiProgress * heightElem + 'px';
    }
   })
  }
 });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700|Open+Sans:400,600,700|Raleway:400,900&display=swap');

*, *:before, *:after {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.elem {
 width: 300px;
 padding: 0 10px;
 background-color: #f4f7ca;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.hide{opacity:0}

#btn {
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 15px;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-weight: bold;
 transition: background-color .2s linear,
    border-color .2s linear,
    color .2s linear;
 border: 2px solid transparent;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
       -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
}

#btn.active {
 background-color: white;
 border-color: black;
 color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="elem hide">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>

<div id="btn">Раскрыть/открыть</div>
```